# How can I fix this specific exception?

Tags: android

I have specific problem related to Android. I am using Acra for bug reports and I'm keeping all bugs in my local database. 
After My last application updates, A specific problem arose.
I am seeing almost 20 new errors on my db each hour which is a simple Nullpointerexception, but when I try my application on different devices, it is working perfectly.
I tried on Samsung phones, Lg Nexus Phone, Asus tablet and genymotion emulator. Occasion is the same whenever I try. I can't fix the problem for I can't  see that on phone.

What can I do to this problem ?

I am also sharing my codes.

my bug report

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.tupbebekailesi.serkanoral.hamilelikrehberi.WeekAlarms: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2567)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:161)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tupbebekailesi.serkanoral.hamilelikrehberi.MotherActivity.week_number(MotherActivity.java:321)
at com.tupbebekailesi.serkanoral.hamilelikrehberi.WeekAlarms.onReceive(WeekAlarms.java:41)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2552)
... 10 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tupbebekailesi.serkanoral.hamilelikrehberi.MotherActivity.week_number(MotherActivity.java:321)
at com.tupbebekailesi.serkanoral.hamilelikrehberi.WeekAlarms.onReceive(WeekAlarms.java:41)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2552)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:161)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1341)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This week_number method

```
public static int week_number() {
        long get_due_date_ms = preferences.getLong( USER_DUE_DATE_MS, 0 );
        long today = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsed_time = today - get_due_date_ms;
        int week_day = ( int ) ( elapsed_time / CalculateActivity.bir_hafta );

        if ( week_day > 39 || week_day < 0 )
            week_day = 0;

        return week_day;
    }
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: What is line number 321?

Comment: prolly `long get_due_date_ms = preferences.getLong( USER_DUE_DATE_MS, 0 );` since only `preferences` can be null in this method

Comment: `preferences` is probably null

Comment: @Willis I shared which is name week_number()

Comment: @Selvin but why sometime It is not throwing an exception ? Do you have an idea ?

Comment: i have no f-idea since you did not provide code how you are asigning preferences ... there is a chance that you are doing it from wrong context ... or in onCreate of some Activity which was killed(whole app) and your BroadcastReciver is "from xml" and you assume that preferences cannot be null ...

Comment: since you have your method as static you probably try to access it somewhere you shouldnt be and at a time where `preferences` was garbage collected

Comment: Thank you for comments. Your ideas are smartly. But I can't understand If I can't see the problems when I test to my application, How will I perceive whether My application works perfectly or not ?

Comment: to be more precise example ... 1. you have `Activity1` and `Activity2`  ... 2. you assume that only `Activity1` starts `Activity2` and it is not possible to starts `Activity2` because  `Activity1` is the only one visible in launcher ... 3. in `onCreate` of `Activity1` you assign `WeekAlarms.preferences` to some not null value and start Activity2 ... 4.  `Activity2` setup instance of `WeekAlarms` BroadcastReciver 5. user starts annother app, 6. OS needs more resources and killing your app 7. user back to your app from recent (so, to `Activity2` which setups reciver back )... and ...

Comment: @Selvin Thank you so much :) I think, I understand where I made a mistake. Just in case, I will test on more scenario in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that preferences could be null. In that case the code below should solve your problem.

```
public static int week_number() {
    if(preferences != null){
        long get_due_date_ms = preferences.getLong( USER_DUE_DATE_MS, 0 );
        long today = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsed_time = today - get_due_date_ms;
        int week_day = ( int ) ( elapsed_time / CalculateActivity.bir_hafta);

        if ( week_day > 39 || week_day < 0 )
            week_day = 0;
        }
        return week_day;
    }
}
```

Comment: First thanx. It would work but  I definitely need value of week_number. Do you have a different idea ?

Comment: You could do something like: if preferences equals null, then put a default value to get_due_date_ms